# Bootstrap 4 overflow hidden not working inside card layouts while animate duration

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have image inside a card layout. I am trying to implement zoom image on mouseover image. When I am mouseoverd on image animation start to scale image. while animation duration image is overflowed from parent wrapper. when animation is completed it hide the overflowed area of the image and show zoomed image.

HTML

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="image-url" />
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            card body ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-wrapper{
    width : 100%;
    overflow : hidden;
    display : block;
}

.card-img-top{
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: Where is the zooming part?

Comment: @CarlBinalla sorry my bad. updated the question. zoom part is the changing scale of the image when mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

run this code

```css
.card-img-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.card-img-wrap img {
  transition: transform .25s;
  width: 100%;
}
.card-img-wrap:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    

<div class="container">         
   <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="card" >                    
      <div class="card-img-wrap">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" />          
      </div>                                    
      <div class="card-block">
 <p class="card-text">Card Body..</p>
      </div>              
    </div>
   </div>
      
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: is there a way to do with without fixed width and heights? I need this to be responsive.

Comment: for img or parent element?

Comment: both and also cannot add fixed width for card-column too

Comment: img size gets larger while removing fixed width

Comment: depending upon the parent element img size changes

Comment: Give the parent element width value in percentage for responsiveness

Comment: adding display: flex make change the behavior of the card layout

Comment: This have same issues with responsive. Card width is fixed

Comment: fixed value is removed